# Equivalent of Python's `dict.get('key', None)` in Objective-C NSMutableArray?

Tags: python, ios, objective-c

Is there a way in objective-c to query an `NSMutableArray` for an object and if the index with which I'm querying is out of bounds, it would not crash, but return some predefined value?

Something like Python has for `dict` type objects, where you do `dictionary.get('key', None)` and if the key is not in the dictionary it returns `None`.

My use case is something like this (not the actual code):

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *array;
@property (nonatomic) int capacity;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.array = [NSMutableArray array];
}

- (void)adder:(NSNumber)number
{
    [self.array addObject:number];
}

- (void)checker
{
    for (int i = 0; i < self.capacity; i++) {
        if ([self.array someMethodToTellIfThereIsAValueAtIndex:i]) {
            NSLog(@"We have a value");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for the index of an object with `indexOfObject` which will return `NSNotFound` if the object is not found. So:

```
index = [self.array indexOfObject:someObject];
if(index != NSNotFound)
    NSLog(@"We have a value at index %lu", index);
```

**EDIT**: Per conversation in comments, it seems that you're wanting to check if any object exists at an index, rather than get the index of a specific object.

To do so, all you need to do is make sure that the index you're checking is less than the `count` of the array you're querying, and is a non-negative integer.

```
if(i < self.array.count)
```

Comment: I don't know ahead of time what specific object it is, I just want to check for the absence of _any_ object. Imagine that I have a list of BOOLs.

Comment: Arrays must hold their values in lowest-index order, so if `arr.count` returns 6, you know that there are objects in indices 0-5. For instance, if you have an array with 2 objects, you can't insert something at index 4. You know that there will be objects in indices 0 and 1.

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I fail to understand how this relates to my question? I do know how arrays work, I just wanted to know if objective-c had some convenience method to do what I ask in my question.

Comment: A convenience method would essentially provide no convenience. In your code, all you have to do is check `if(i < self.array.count)` and as long as you have a non-negative value in `i` you know that you'll have an object.

Comment: If that's the case, I'm also happy. If you can, please include your last comment in your answer. Thanks!